# Opposing dice pools for successes

Tags: anydice

I’m working with AnyDice trying to figure out how to do an opposed roll between an attacker and a defender, each using separate pools of d6s, where the attacker succeeds >=4 and the defender succeeds >=5, with the winner being the one with more successes (ties going to the defender), and an output for who wins based on various sized dice pools.

I can do everything separately, but cannot figure out how to bring it all together. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
APOOL: 4
DPOOL: 3

ADICE: d{0,1}
DDICE: d{0,0,1}

output APOOLdADICE > DPOOLdDDICE
```

[anydice](https://anydice.com/program/352d5)

Set the APOOL and DPOOL to whatever numbers you like. You can put them in loops if you want multiple outputs.

Comment: Possibly clearer equivalent notation: `ADICE: d6 >= 4`, `DDICE: d6 >= 5`